# How to make a SSIS transaction in my case?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I am using SSIS 2008.

Let a person be defined by PersonID, a number. In my SSIS package, for each person,  I first load some info into Table1 (with execute sql task) and then some info into Table2 (with execute sql task). I want this entire process to be considered as a transaction. That is, the transaction is complete only when information for A person is loaded both into Table1 and Table2. If we could not load info into Table2, then info already loaded in Table1 should not be committed.

How do I do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Place both of your loads into a sequence container set transaction option to required in the properties tab. Done.

Comment: This article expands on @Zane's comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1585/how-to-use-transactions-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/

Comment: Thanks @mr.Reband I would have done a better answer but I can't post images at work...

Comment: @mr.Reband - Thanks. The essence of that article is given by Zane. That is what i was really looking for.

Comment: @Zane - I suggest that you put your comment as an answer. I will select it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place both of your loads into a sequence container set transaction option to required in the properties tab. Done. Included is an article in case you need [additional details](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1585/how-to-use-transactions-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/).

Comment: Thanks. But none of my connections work now. Can't save the password problem. I put passwords, tested connections and then encrypt all with password. Still cannot use my connections. Why is this happening ? :(

Comment: Do you mean your connection strings?

Comment: You may want to take some screenshots and post some more details about your package I will be able to provide better assistance then.

Comment: Yes, all the stuff you see in an OLE DB connections editor - servername, username, password, save password etc.

Comment: WARNING !!! There is a problem in using this method - See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869276/cannot-connect-to-database-after-putting-tasks-in-sequence-container

Comment: Well there is less of a problem using this method as there is a problem with your particular set up of connection strings.